# Memory leaks in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, profiling, firebug

Can we find any where the `memory leaks` should be exactly happened in `Java Script`?

Which one is best ? `Google chrome` or `Fire bug` ?

I used chrome for CPU profiling but it doesn't shows the line where memory leak happend.

Any suggestions ? or how to find `Memory leak` in `javaScript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be looking at CPU profiling. Chrome's inspector-window has a way for you to take [**Heap Snapshots**](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling).

> Heap Snapshot profiles show memory distribution among your page's
>   JavaScript objects and related DOM nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I got the snap shots.But all looks like memory address.Its difficult and don't know how to find where memory leaks happened in my script?

Comment: @KitePlayer Are you in the `Containment` view, after selecting the snapshot? That should give you a fair idea of memory consumption.

Comment: +1 for your answer...Can you give suggest any good tutorial or blog other than chrome developer tools ?